# V-Brake brake blocks non-centred posts

Tags: brakes

I just bought some Clarks CPS301 Brake Blocks (V-Brake brake blocks). The threaded posts are positioned slightly off-centre, towards the front. This is different from my old, unbranded ones where the posts are dead centre. Why is this? What are the advantanges or disadvantages of the off-centre posts? My bicycle is a Ridgeback Meteor commuter bike. The only possible explanation I could find is in the comments of [this post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14567/are-v-brake-pads-compatible-with-cantilever-brakes).

[image: Clarks CPS301 Brake Blocks]
[image]

Comment: The comment by Jahaziel is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The slightly off centre, forward position of the mount post is (IMO) most likely designed to optimise the brake force vs. pull and force distribution ... also relating to "toe-in".

Typically when fitting brake blocks of rim brakes you 'toe-in' the leading (front) end of the pad slightly so that this part makes contact with the braking surface first. This way the rest of the block is pulled on to the braking surface by the twisting force due to the rotation of the wheel. This also helps to reduce the necessary force/travel applied to the brake lever to bring the whole block in to contact with the braking service and progressively through the braking motion.

The slightly forward position of the mount is no doubt due to a calculation the optimal position for the force point action on the pads with regards/consideration of these other forced involved, providing the quickest and strongest application of brake block to braking surface.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie ... I've already come to recognise your name on hear as a powerhouse contributor in this community, so your comment comes as high praise indeed!! Thanks again!  =)